# SelectFeature fails on a small polygon on top of a larger polygon

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm using `new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature` to draw polygons and `OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature` to select a specific polygon. I'm drawing one polgon and then a smaller polygon on top of the first one.

```
PolyA is a large polygon(50 x 50)
PolyB is a smaller polgon (10 x 10) drawn within (on top of) PolyA
```

Initially I can select and unselect PolyB correctly. However, once I have selected and unselected PolyA, PolyB is now hidden behind it and can no longer be selected.

Why is that and what can I do to resolve it?

select code (straightforward)

```
select  = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer,
     {
          highlightOnly: true,  
          clickout: true, toggle: true,
          onSelect: function(feature) {

          //do stuff    
     }
 });
```

Comment: show some code so we know how you are using the `OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature`

Comment: Show the "do stuff" code.  Especially, are you changing the x, y or z-index of the selected item?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with selecting multiple features at same time. after this you need to do is that put all features under `for loop`.

```
var info = []

select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer, {
box: true,
multiple: true,
onSelect: function(f){
for (var a = 0; a < f.length; a++){
info.push(f[a].attributes.featureName) // or anything you want
}
}   
});
```

beside this:

`layer.selectedFeatures` returns you as a result of all selected features..

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't address the issue. The issue is why a selected-then-unselected feature(polygon) remains in front of a feature it was originally behind.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to enable zIndexing on vector layer's rendererOptions and assign 'graphicZIndex' to each feature. Make sure that upper features has smaller 'graphicZIndex' values. Following are some sample code:

```
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector layer", {
    styleMap: your_style_map,
    rendererOptions: {zIndexing: true}
});

//Set the featureAdded function to the OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature, where
//you can assign the graphicZIndex to each feature you add on layer.
var drawControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vector, {
    ... // other options
    featureAdded: featureAdded
});


var current_z_index = 1000; // global variable to store the new feature's z index

// featureAdded function
function featureAdded(feature) {
    var default_style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default);
    var feature_style = OpenLayers.Util.extend(default_style, {graphicZIndex: current_z_index});
    current_z_index++;
    feature.style = feature_style; // With these lines, we can make sure the features added later will always on top
}
```